# How do you replace all strings with a specific prefix with a variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What I am trying to do find all instances in a string with "{{msgStr." as a prefix and replace it with a variable.  For example:

```
var msgStr = {
    h1Text: 'test',
    pText: 'test2'
}

var string = '<h1>{{msgStr.h1Text}}</h1><p>{{msgStr.pText}}</p>';
var pattern = new RegExp("{{msgStr.(.+?)}}","g");
alert(string.replace(pattern, msgStr[$1]));
```

The problem is that msgStr[$1] is returning undefined.  I tried msgStr["$1"] with the same result.  If I do just "$1", it outputs h1Text and pText, which is what I am trying to use like msgStr["h1Text"].

Not sure what I need to do to get this working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [callback as a second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for `String.prototype.replace`:

```
str.replace(/{{msgStr\.(.+?)}}/g, function(_, c) {
    return msgStr[c];
});
```

Comment: Not a JS user, but, looked at that spec for the parameters for that replacement function (callback). If I wanted to get the total string, would I have to list all the capture group arguments, ex: 2 capture groups total `match, p1, p2, offset, string` ? What if I only wanted capture group 1 (same regex), would it be ok if the arg list is just `match, p1` ?

Comment: @sln Answering your first question, *no*, for such cases JavaScript has [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object, which is available for all functions, so to get the last parameter you may use `arguments[arguments.length-1]`. Regarding the second question, *yes*, in JS you may specify any number of arguments in the function definition, as well as in the function call.

Comment: I see. If I understand `arguments` object correctly, in your answer above as example, I could use `function() { return msgStr[arguments[arguments.length-3]];}` the variable in this list that is capture group 1, and `arguments[arguments.length-4]]` is capture group 0 ? (I know it shouldn't be done this way). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this (just pass in the `function` as the second parameter for `replace` function)

```
var msgStr = {
  h1Text: 'test',
  pText: 'test2'
}

var string = '<h1>{{msgStr.h1Text}}</h1><p>{{msgStr.pText}}</p>';
string.replace(/{{msgStr.(.+?)}}/g, function(substr, match){return msgStr[match]})
```

**EDIT** I guess I'm a little late, the page didn't refresh, didn't see the answer above :)